# Schtasks succeeds but application won't show up

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

I am trying to run Notepad.exe via Schtasks.

I first created a scheduled task, named "secheduledNotepad".

> SUCCESS: The scheduled task
>   "secheduledNotepad" has successfully
>   been created.

Then I tried to run it:

```
C:\Windows\system32>Schtasks /Run /TN "secheduledNotepad"
```

It runs, as I receive the message:

> SUCCESS: Attempted to run the
>   scheduled task "secheduledNotepad".

and I can even see notepad.exe in Windows Task Manager.

But... **it is nowhere to be found on the screen!**

Why? and how do I fix this?

(I am using Windows 7 Starter)

Comment: Did you tell it to run under your own user context?

Comment: @Randolph Potter How do I tell it to run under my own user context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there. Open the task Scheduler and then select Microsoft. Then on the right hand side select Create a task the second on down. That will open it. One the first page down the bottom the last check box. "Run with the highest privileges" Check that.

Good luck,
R Scotti

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.  I'm running windows 8.1
The newly created task seems to default to run only if the machine is on AC power.
When I unticked the option on the Conditions tab it worked fine.

Comment: Question was for Windows 7, but might be helpful anyway

Comment: Understood, but there's not much for 8.1 at the moment so I can't be the only one who'll end up here. :)